# EC2 - LAMP Memory Issue

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, lamp

I have the latest Amazon Linux AMI running on a medium instance with 4gb of Ram.

LAMP server is setup with a single Wordpress instance. I am having memory issues that I can't seem to pinpoint my issue. I am new to linux, and am unsure of how to pinpoint our issue.

Apache will report:

Sat Apr 18 04:27:36 2015 error (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process

MYSQL will report:

```
150418 4:28:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150418 4:28:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Version: '5.5.42' socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
150418 04:28:24 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150418 04:28:24 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
150418 4:28:24 Note Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150418 4:28:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150418 4:28:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150418 4:28:24 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
150418 4:28:24 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150418 4:28:24 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 64.0M
InnoDB: mmap(68681728 bytes) failed; errno 12
150418 4:28:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150418 4:28:24 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
150418 4:28:24 ERROR Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150418 4:28:24 ERROR Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150418 4:28:24 ERROR Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150418 4:28:24 ERROR Aborting
150418 4:28:24 Note /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
150418 04:28:24 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

MYSQL Conf:

```
mysqld
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
query_cache_size=8M
tmp_table_size=16M
max_heap_table_size=16M
thread_cache_size=4
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M

mysqld_safe
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

HTTPD Conf: (Prefork)

```
prefork MPM
StartServers: number of server processes to start
MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
ServerLimit: maximum value for MaxClients for the lifetime of the server
MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers 8
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 15
ServerLimit 256
MaxClients 256
MaxRequestsPerChild 3000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What does your memory distribution (consumption) look like before the crashes?

Comment: I am seeing the exact same issue in my logs.  Can't SSH to the instance.  Have to detach the drive and attach to another instance in order to read the logs because the issue occurs during/right after startup.  Issue started occurring right after updating wordpress, all plugins, and themes.